# Wordpress admin notice always showing same message

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

On the admin dashboard, I display admin notice to display the result of changes. I have production site and staging site. On the staging site, it works well. If I made changes, it's displaying the notice of appropriate message. But on production, it's same code as staging site. When I made changes, it's displaying the "cached" notice but not the appropriate message.

Here is my approach to solve this.

```
$flash_messages = maybe_unserialize(get_option('wp_flash_messages', array()));
print_r(flash_messages); exit;
```

This displays the 'cached' message.

```
delete_option('wp_flash_messages');
$flash_messages = maybe_unserialize(get_option('wp_flash_messages', array()));
print_r($flash_messages); exit;
```

I added delete_option() before get the message. But it returns the 'cached' message again.

**EDIT : I cleared server cache as well.**

It's really annoyed.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue is because of `get_option()` function is cached.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/#source

Here you can see the function get cached data first and if not, look through db and get option.

**ANSWER**

```
wp_cache_flush();
```

This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can delete cacle from WPEngine is a managed WordPress hosting provider. They run their own caching solution, so their customers don’t need to install a caching plugin.

If you are unable to notice changes take effect immediately, then you can easily clear WPEngine cache from your WordPress admin area.

[image]

2)  You can also delete cache by using wp super cache plugin[image]